# query results of signed in user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ticket-system

I currently have a ticket system built and I would like users to view the status of their Open and Closed tickets.

I can query the database and get all tickets to display, but I only want the logged in users tickets to show. How would I achieve this. Been at it a few days now and I'm at a loss.

**What I have:**

**ROUTE** (This returns a 404 due to the `{ticketId}`) / Note: If I remove the `{ticketId}` from the Route I get the Type error: `*Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController::openTickets(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"*`

```
Route::get('/tickets/open-tickets/{ticketId}','TicketsController@openTickets')->name('open-tickets');
```

**TICKETS CONTROLLER**

```
public function openTickets($ticketId){

$tickets=Classified::find($ticketId);
$ticketId = Auth::user('id');
$tickets = DB::table('tickets')->orderBy('st_id', 'DESC')->where('status', '=', 'OPEN')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->paginate(4);
return view('tickets.open-tickets',compact('tickets'));
```

**Ticket MODEL**

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    use Notifiable, HasPermissionsTrait;

    protected $ticketId = 'st_id';
    protected $guarded=[];  

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
     'created' => Events\NewTicket::class
 ];
}
```

**WORKING QUERY TO DISPLAY ALL TICKETS**

```
public function openTickets(){
    $tickets = DB::table('tickets')->orderBy('st_id', 'DESC')->where('status', '=', 'OPEN')->paginate(4);
return view('tickets.open-tickets',compact('tickets'));
```

I should mention that I changed my id to st_id on the tickets table as I'm using the ID to display the ticket number like this `201804001`

Again I'm just looking for a solution to have the logged in user view their tickets and NOT all tickets in the database.

Image of Tickets Table:
[image]

Comment: Where is the `$id` variable being defined in this clause `'user_id', '=', $id`?

Comment: what you need is relationships, check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I'm trying to match the `id` of the Auth user to the `user_id` in the tickets table.

Comment: can you show the users and the tickets tables ?

Comment: @echo - yes, but I don't see where the variable `$id` is actually being defined... did you mean to write `$id = Auth::user('id');` in the line above it? (rather than overwriting your value for `$ticketId`)?

Comment: @BenD yes apologize, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Hussein I added an image of the table

Comment: cool then as @Sacha said

Comment: @echo I'm not sure if you're understanding what I'm saying, but that code has an outright error in it. `$id` isn't defined anywhere. It looks like you have a host of issues there (you seem to be trying to use a specific resource route to return a list, which is very confusing), but the first thing to do is fix that bad variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a Ticket model but you're using the DB facade to query the tickets table.

Instead, associate **Tickets** with **Users** via a **one-to-many relationship**.

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

In your User class:

```
    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }
```

Now you can do `$user->tickets()->where('status', 'OPEN')->get();` to get all the open tickets for that user.

Even further, you can add a **scope** to the Ticket model.

In your Ticket class:

```
public function scopeOpen($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'OPEN');
}
```

This will allow you to make your queries more fluent:

`$user->tickets()->open()->get();`

To associate a ticket with a user, simply do something along the following lines:

```
$user->tickets()->save(new Ticket([
    'status' => 'open',
    'title'  => 'Problem logging in',
    'body'   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
]));
```

For more information about Eloquent relationships (specifically one-to-many relationships), [see the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

To list all of a user's open tickets, use the following route:

`Route::get('tickets/open-tickets/', 'TicketsController@index');`

To show an individual ticket, you'll want the following route:

`Route::get('tickets/open-tickets/{ticket}', 'TicketsController@show')`

Use the following methods in your `TicketsController`:

```
public function index()
{
    // user() is a helper for Auth::user()
    $tickets = user()->tickets()->open()->paginate(4);

    return view('tickets.open-tickets', compact('tickets'));
}

public function show(Ticket $ticket)
{
    // If the ticket does not belong to the logged in user, abort
    if ($ticket->user_id != user()->id) {
        abort(403, 'This is not your ticket');
    }

    return view('tickets.show', compact('ticket'));
}
```

You'll notice that the `show` method in your controller type-hints the `Ticket` model. This is called route-model binding, which is very useful and you can [read more about that here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding).

It may seem like I'm overcomplicating things compared to your original code, but trust me, it's better to understand these things early on! They'll help you a whole lot during development.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry for my lack of knowledge, but where would `$user->tickets()->where('status', 'OPEN')->get();` go? In my Ticket Model or TicketsController? Pretty new to Laravel and trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: That would go in your tickets controller. I will update my answer to show how you might get an individual ticket.

Comment: hey I have one last question if you don't mind. I keep getting the error `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\user()`. How would I fix this? It's happening here. `if ($ticket->user_id != user()->id) {`

Comment: @echo it's `if(auth()->user()->id != $ticket->user_id)`